# Python not insert into mysql Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, insert

My algorithm is not able to insert values in my mysql database and I have no idea why.
Pls help

```
countlist=['Apple', 2099, 'Tesla', 2799, 'Microsoft', 199, 'Google', 701, 'Amazon', 2899, 'Facekook/meta', 99, 'Nvidia', 798, 'Tencent', 0, 'Johnson and Johnson', 428, 'JP Morgan', 735, 'United Health Group ', 553, 'LVMA ', 1, 'Walmart Inc. ', 395, 'Visa ', 198, 'Home Depot Inc. ', 199, 'Protector & Gamble Co. ', 499, 'Mastercard', 199, 'Bank of America Corp', 299, 'Nestle SA', 0, 'Samsung Electronics Co ltd', 0, 'Exxon-Mobil', 151, 'Roche Holding Ltd', 0, 'Toyota Motor Corporation', 599, 'Alibaba Holding Group Ltd', 0, 'Pfizer', 399, 'Berkshire Hathaway Inc.', 47, 'ASML Holding NV', 99, 'Coca Cola', 98, 'Chevron', 986, 'Walt Disney', 99, 'Adobe System Inc.', 96, 'Broadcom Inc.', 288, 'AbbVie Inc.', 169, 'PepsiCo', 199, 'Eli Lilly & Co', 299, "L'Oréal", 70, 'Thermo Fisher Scientific', 199, 'Cisco Systems Inc.', 143, 'Accenture PLC', 199, 'Costco Wholesale Corp', 399, 'Abbot Laboratories', 199, 'Comcast Corp', 90, 'Verizon Communications', 619, 'Salesforce Inc', 799, 'Oracle Corp', 358, 'Wells Fargo & Co', 461, 'Qualcomm Inc', 374, 'Danaher Corp', 176, 'Novartis ADR', 67, 'Merck & Co', 598, 'BP', 0, 'Intel', 320, 'Royal Dutch Shell A', 0, "McDonald's", 1197, 'Netflix', 825, 'Nike', 99, 'Novo Nordisk B', 0, 'Morgan Stanley', 599, 'China Construction Bank', 0, 'Astra Zeneca', 14, 'AT&T', 99, 'Texas Instruments', 628, 'United Parcel Service (Class B)', 299, 'Prosus N.V.', 0, 'Linde', 3299, 'BHP Billiton Ltd.', 0, 'Royal Bank of Canada', 98, 'Charles Schwab', 64, 'Philip Morris International', 999, 'Union Pacific Corp', 99, "Lowe's Companies", 499, 'Hermes International S.C.A', 0, 'Intuit', 77, 'PayPal', 199, 'SAP', 499, 'Meituan Registered Shs ', 0, 'Nextera Energy', 299, 'Toronto-Dominion Bank', 99, 'TOTAL ', 0, 'AMD', 99, 'Sony', 1099, 'Bristol-Myers Squibb', 188, 'CVS Health Corp', 797, 'China Mobile', 0, 'HSBC Holdings ', 0, 'Christian Dior', 0, 'Honeywell International', 2199, 'American Express', 109, 'Medtronic', 1866, 'Raytheon Technologies ', 3693, 'T-Mobile US', 76, 'Siemens', 0, 'Keyence', 0, 'Sanofi-Aventis', 1, 'Citigroup', 399, 'Unilever plc', 0, 'Amgen', 83, 'Volkswagen Vz.', 0]

import mysql.connector

mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
    host="----",
    user="-----",
    password="----",
    database="aktien",
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
date=previous_day+month+year
date_ready="erwaehnungen"+date+""

mycursor = mydb.cursor() 
query = "ALTER TABLE aktien ADD "+date_ready+" VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT'0'" 
mycursor.execute(query) 



i=0
while i!=len(countlist):
    stockname= countlist[i]
    stockvalue= [countlist[i+1]]

    sql = "INSERT INTO `aktien` (erwaehnungen) VALUES (%s);"
    val = (stockvalue)
    
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()
    i=i+2
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

The program should insert every second value of the list countlist.
There is no error from Python and when I start the program it says that he inserted the values but in the database there are no values.

Answer (score 0):

The Best practice is to close the connection after executing your queries.
Try adding these at end of your code:

```
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```